# How does the Android MediaMuxer works with raw-video and raw-audio?

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediacodec, video-recording

I'm trying to record (screen)-video and (microphone)-audio of my device. For my video-screen-recording I've used MediaProjection to get raw-video data and MediaCodec and MediaMuxer to create the video-file, which works fine.

Now I want to add an audio-recording, especially the microphone audio. For this I used the AudioRecord class to get the raw-audio data of my device-microphone. The problem I'm facing now is to get all the raw-streams (video & audio) together with the MediaMuxer, for example should it be synchronous or asynchronous?

Because the audio and video recording process are in two diffrent threads, so I don't know when I have to call the writeSampleData()-method of MediaMuxer. Or should I first write all video-data with the MediaMuxer and then *afterwards* the audio-data? Is it even possible to call the MediaMuxer in two different threads at "the same time"? And how can I guarantee that audio and video are synchronized during the muxing?